# Error al conectar mi JavaScripts con mi base de datos sql server

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server

Esty intentando crear un proyecto web con mi base de datos SQL (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio).
Al seguir los pasos indicados en su web https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15, me da el siguiente error al intentar conectar con la base de datos.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not definedat index.html:41**

```
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
    var config = {  
        server: 'sqlDesarollo',  //update me
        authentication: {
            type: 'default',
            options: {
                userName: 'admin', //update me
                password: 'admin'  //update me
            }
        },
        options: {
            // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need encryption:
            encrypt: true,
            database: 'DBPrueba'  //update me
        }
    };  
    var connection = new Connection(config);  
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
        // If no error, then good to proceed.
        console.log("Connected");  
    });  
</script>
```

¿A que se debe este error?

Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js/31931649

Comment: Estás copiando el ejemplo de forma literal y así no va a funcionar. Te recomiendo descargar el código completo del ejercicio (el enlace de Github que está ahí mismo en la página que nos indicas) para que puedas hacer tu implementación de forma completa partiendo de ese ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

me llama mucho la atención de la palabra `</script>` en el código, ¿estás usando esto dentro de un archivo html?

Tal y cómo lo indica [el enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15) que compartiste anteriormente, esto es para ser utilizado con Node.JS, quiere decir que el código lo debes implementar en un archivo .js y ejecutarlo con el comando `node`.

Te invito a ver el siguiente [link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/) de introducción a NodeJS.

Por otra parte, estás usando un servidor local, entonces la opción `encrypt` debe ser `false`.

```
options: {
            // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need encryption:
            encrypt: false,
            database: 'DBPrueba'  //update me
        }
```

Comment: El ````</script>```` habrá sido un error. Estoy intentando ejecutar el archivo dbConexion.js